# When using DOMPDF to download pdf, page shown blank

Tags: php, wordpress, dompdf

When download DOMPDF using jquery ajax in Wordpress php.The pdf downloaded but page its blank.

below code file is **generatepdf.php**

[generatepdf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M61J.png)

**test.php**

```
Generate PDF


    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#generatePdfButton').click(function() {
            // Make an AJAX request to generate.php
            $.ajax({
                url: 'generatepdf.php',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(response) {
                    // Handle success
                    var blob = new Blob(\[response\], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    var link = document.createElement('a');
                    link.href = url;
                    link.download = 'test.pdf';
                    link.click();
                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    console.error('Failed to generate PDF:', error);
                    // Optionally, display an error message to the user
                }
            });
        });
    });



Generate PDF
```

I want to render html properly when call jquery ajax to download pdf.

Comment: Why use AJAX for this? You can simply have a link to `generatepdf.php`. A debug question: if you access `generatepdf.php` directly and save the result as a PDF, what do you see? Also note this: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) Otherwise I could have tested it myself.

Comment: Yes you said correct, but when click a button , I want to download a pdf using jquery ajax. so i tried like this